# Merge into, When not matched by source and target in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, azure-sql-database

I have 3 tables: Source, Target, Temp

My requirement is to perform a merge into based on primary key constraints in such a way that

1. When the source = target, UPDATE target with values of source
2. When it is not matched by target, meaning records from source are in target, I have insert the records from source to target
3. After all this, when the target record still remains unchanged or not updated(when not matched by source), then I have to write those records to the Temp table and delete them from target.

I am stuck at writing the records to Temp table and deleting the same records from target table.

```
    MERGE INTO dbo.Target_TBL AS Target USING dbo.Source_TBL AS Source
ON Target.SourceCode = Source.SourceCode
   AND Target.Date = Source.Date
   AND Target.Code = Source.Code
   AND Target.Number = Source.Number
   AND Target.Country = Source.Country
   AND Target.CategoryCode = Source.CategoryCode
   AND Target.TypeCode = Source.TypeCode

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
   SET Target.Qty = Source.Qty,
       Target.RecordUpdateTimestamp = Source.RecordUpdateTimestamp

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    
   INSERT (SourceCode, Date, Code, Number, Country, CategoryCode, Qty, RecordCreationTimestamp, RecordUpdateTimestamp, TypeCode)
      VALUES (Source.SourceCode, Source.Date, Source.Code,
    Source.Number, Source.Country, Source.CategoryCode,
    Source.Qty, Source.RecordCreationTimestamp, Source.RecordUpdateTimestamp, Source.TypeCode)
    
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
```

I tried 'insert into Temp table' but it was not allowed under 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE'. Please let me know how I can write to Temp table and also delete the records from the target table when not matched by source.

Comment: So what is your question? You've just listed some requirements; you've not asked anything. We can't answer your question if we don't know what your question is.

Comment: *"How do I write a merge into query for the above scenario?"* Where exactly is it you're stuck? You've tagged [[tag:upsert]] so are you looking to use a `MERGE`, like your title and question says, or an Upsert? What about the documentation/articles/Q&A's you;ve read didn't you understand? What was your attempt? Why didn't it work?  Did it error? Provide unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Something else?

Comment: Have you had a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on `MERGE` and/or Aaron Bertrand's collection of [articles](//sqlblog.org/merge) it (and why you should be using an Upsert)? If not, why not? You should, they're both excellent places to start.

Comment: *" then I have to write those records to the Temp table and delete them from target."* Why put them into a temporary table and delete them? Why not just delete them? Are you planning to do *something else* with that data in the temporary table?

Comment: yes, it needs to be retained but only in temp table. @ThomA

Comment: A temporary table, as its name suggests, is **temporary** it won't be retained.

Comment: It will be retained for few days, say a month. @ThomA

Comment: Not in a temporary table it won't be, again, that's why it's called a **temporary** table, it's *temporary*. A temporary table is implicit dropped as soon as the scope that created ends. If you want to *retain* the deleted data then `OUTPUT` it into a user table in your database. This is most certainly starting to sound like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: The whole concept is to not have those records in target table, but should be in another table (table name: temp_table). I am stuck at this part of inserting the unmtched records to temp_table and deleting the records from target table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comments you're thinking about this the wrong way; you don't want to `INSERT` the data you want to `DELETE` into a temporary table and then `DELETE` the rows. Instead you should `DELETE` the rows and `INSERT` the details of those rows into a temporary table. You can achieve this by using an `OUTPUT` clause.

Firstly, some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.DestinationTable (ID int, SomeValue varchar(3));

CREATE TABLE dbo.SourceTable (ID int, SomeValue varchar(3))
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable (ID,
                              SomeValue)
VALUES (1,'abc'),
       (2,'def');

INSERT INTO dbo.SourceTable (ID,
                             SomeValue)
VALUES(1,'bcd'),
      (3,'xyz');
GO
```

Personally I would suggest against a `MERGE` (I've already linked to a bunch of [articles](https://sqlblog.org/merge) why), but I'll show the solution here anyway. As a `MERGE` can do `INSERT`, `UPDATE` *and* `DELETE` operations you'll need to capture what that action was, using `$action`, and then `DELETE` the rows in your temporary table you don't need. This gives you the following solution:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #DeletedData (Action nvarchar(10), ID int, SomeValue varchar(3));

GO

MERGE INTO dbo.DestinationTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS DT
USING dbo.SourceTable ST ON DT.ID = ST.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET SomeValue = ST.SomeValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ID,SomeValue)
    VALUES(ST.ID,ST.SomeValue)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT $action,
       Deleted.ID,
       Deleted.SomeValue
INTO #DeletedData;
GO
DELETE FROM #DeletedData
WHERE Action != 'DELETE';
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DestinationTable;
GO
SELECT *
FROM #DeletedData;
```

Personally, however, and as mentioned, I would use an Upsert. This also makes capturing only the deleted rows easier. This would look like the following:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE #DeletedData (ID int, SomeValue varchar(3));

UPDATE DT WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET SomeValue = ST.SomeValue
FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT
     JOIN dbo.SourceTable ST ON  DT.ID = ST.ID;

INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable (ID,
                                  SomeValue)
SELECT ST.ID,
       ST.SomeValue
FROM dbo.SourceTable ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT
                  WHERE DT.ID = ST.ID);

DELETE DT
OUTPUT Deleted.ID,
       Deleted.SomeValue
INTO #DeletedData
FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.SourceTable ST
                  WHERE ST.ID = DT.ID);


COMMIT;
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T69nTKfH)

Comment: Why is the #DeletedData temp table having records for action insert and update as well. Shouldn't it be just for DELETE?. I mean the part before executing `DELETE FROM #DeletedData
WHERE Action != 'DELETE';`

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise, @Sivaani ? You have all 3 paths in the `MERGE`, do you'd get data for all 3.